# Is it possible to use INT8 input layer for tensorrt?

Tags: nvidia, tensorrt

I want to have input layer as 8bit integer, to avoid int->float conversion on CPU:

```
        ITensor* data = network->addInput(
                m_InputBlobName.c_str(), nvinfer1::DataType::kINT8,
                DimsCHW{static_cast<int>(m_InputC), static_cast<int>(m_InputH),
                        static_cast<int>(m_InputW)});
```

but it gives me this error message:

```
[E] [TRT] Parameter check failed at: ../builder/Network.cpp::addInput::466, condition: type != DataType::kINT8
```

Is it possible to make it work, or INT8 is only intended to be used for approximate calculations?

Answer (score 1):

I found python api with addInput description:

```
add_input()
addInput(const char *name, DataType type, Dims dimensions)=0 -> ITensor *
```

Add an input tensor to the network.

The name of the input tensor is used to find the index into the buffer array for an engine built from the network.

**Parameters:**

1. name (*) – The name of the tensor.
2. type (*) – The type of the data held in the tensor.
3. dimensions (*) – The dimensions of the tensor.

Only `DataType::kFLOAT, DataType::kHALF and DataType::kINT32` are valid input tensor types. The volume of the dimensions, including the maximum batch size, must be less than `2^30` elements.

*Returns:*  The new tensor or None if there is an error.

Comment: I also hope to use int8 type as input image, have you solved it？

Comment: looks like thats not possible, you have to convert to float first...